# What is the difference when assigning a bash variable value with this syntax?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, syntax

Sorry if this is something really simple or has already been asked, but due to the nature of the question I cannot think of any search terms to put on search engines.

Lately I have seen some bash scripts that they assign variable values like this:

```
$ MY_BASH_VAR=${MY_BASH_VAR:-myvalue}
$ echo "$MY_BASH_VAR"
myvalue
```

What is the difference from the most common way of assigning a value like this:

```
MY_BASH_VAR=myvalue
$ echo "$MY_BASH_VAR"
myvalue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

```
${parameter:-word}  Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

This provides a default value : MY_BASH_VAR keeps its value if defined otherwise, it takes the default "myvalue"

```
bruce@lorien:~$ A=42
bruce@lorien:~$ A=${A:-5}
bruce@lorien:~$ echo $A
42
```

Comment: Note that with `:-`, `A` will also receive the default value if it is currently set to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the `$MY_BASH_VAR` was already set. In this case, it will keep the same value. If not, it will get `myvalue`.

case 1) `$MY_BASH_VAR` already set.

```
$ MY_BASH_VAR="hello"
$ MY_BASH_VAR=${MY_BASH_VAR:-myvalue}
$ echo "$MY_BASH_VAR"
hello
```

case 2) `$MY_BASH_VAR` not previously set.

```
$ MY_BASH_VAR=${MY_BASH_VAR:-myvalue}
$ echo "$MY_BASH_VAR"
myvalue
```

case 3) `$MY_BASH_VAR` set to the empty string.

```
$ MY_BASH_VAR=""
$ MY_BASH_VAR=${MY_BASH_VAR:-myvalue}
$ echo "$MY_BASH_VAR"
myvalue
```

Comment: Note that with `:-`, `MY_BASH_VAR` will also receive the default value if it is currently set to the empty string.

Comment: Oh, that's true, didn't remember to mention it in my answer. Just updated it. Thanks!